# Using on-disk cache for big data (gigabytes) with Spring cache abstraction

Tags: java, spring-cache

I need to cache a large object (about the size if 6GB) in a single cache key and to store this cache on disk. 
I am querying the data from Oracle Table and saving it using Spring @Cacheable annotation.

Which Spring cache storage should be the best for this scenario?

I have tried to use ehCache - it is good when saving data to heap, but for disk storage I am getting some error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
        at java.nio.Bits.reserveMemory(Bits.java:693) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(DirectByteBuffer.java:123) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
```

When giving more memory getting maxobjectgraph size error, increasing the object graph size is also not solving the problem.
Is there any additional setting i need to do, or my usecase is not valid?

I am trying to use this data as single blob of cache in desk to save the network round-trip to oracleDB . Then further saving subset of this data in RAM as cache to improve upon search ability.

Comment: please add the error

Comment: trying to reword to be better comprehensible, removing superflouus reference to Oracle, replacing abstraction with storage as it mentions specific cache storage

Comment: Thanks, Complete problem description is here here. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/ehcache-users/ehcache-core/-CVbCpCSIOc